# cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference on layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Its mvc 4.Can any one help me?!

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Order(int id, int hotelId)
{
    ViewBag.PackageFrames = packageRepo.GetPackageFrames(id);
    ViewBag.PackageId = id;
    ViewBag.HotelId = hotelId;
    return View();
}
```

and `ViewBag.PackageFrames` has three records.

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Range";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<section class="header-page fade-up" style="background: url(/Images/Packages/Backgrounds/@Model.Background) 50% 0 fixed;">
    <div class="bounce-in animate4">
        <h1 class="header-pagetitle bye">@Model.Name</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="internalpage">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
            @{List<Paristan.AgencyPortal.Model.Packages.PackageFrame> packageFrames = (List<Paristan.AgencyPortal.Model.Packages.PackageFrame>)ViewBag.PackageFrames;}
            <select id="packageFrame" packageId="@ViewBag.PackageId" hotelId="@ViewBag.HotelId">
                @foreach (var packageFrame in packageFrames)
                {
                    <option value="@packageFrame.PackageFrameId">@packageFrame.FromDate - @packageFrame.ToDate</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the `_ViewStart`:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and the _Layout is in `~/Views/Shared` folder and nothing is null. but I see the following error on `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` line.

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ViewBag.packageFrames  in foreach.

```
   @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Range";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }


<section class="header-page fade-up" style="background: url(/Images/Packages/Backgrounds/@Model.Background) 50% 0 fixed;">
    <div class="bounce-in animate4">
        <h1 class="header-pagetitle bye">@Model.Name</h1>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="internalpage">
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
            @{List<Paristan.AgencyPortal.Model.Packages.PackageFrame> packageFrames = (List<Paristan.AgencyPortal.Model.Packages.PackageFrame>)ViewBag.PackageFrames;}
            <select id="packageFrame" packageId="@ViewBag.PackageId" hotelId="@ViewBag.HotelId">
                @foreach (var packageFrame in ViewBag.packageFrames)
                {
                    <option value="@packageFrame.PackageFrameId">@packageFrame.FromDate - @packageFrame.ToDate</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have @Model.Name in .cshtml and no model defined in controller